# What functions or link do i use

Tags: php

I am doing my final year project and i have no idea how to i do this function.
The language i am using is php and heres how to function will go

1. user creates an input in the form called major occurrence( i did this form page)
2. After creating there should be like a map on the home page to show where this major occurrence thing happens at for example in the school canteen (since i am doing my project related to school)
3. When showing, there should be a indicator for example a blinker or something or a tickr for the major occurance
4. By clicking the tickr, it should link me to the details of the major occurrence form page

Comment: What is your question? You just want us to list functions?

Comment: Not really i have problem coding it out, any idea how should i go about it? sorry first time using this forum, pardon me for not being clear

Comment: We will not write the code for you! Please attempt the problem yourself then we will be more than happy to help with any specific problems you have. Do some Google research on Map widgets and tickers in php for instance.

Comment: yeah yeah i dont mean by asking you guys to write code for me, just love to have the function name so i can research more on it and try it out myself. Like the functions i could link and etc.

Comment: I suggested a few things you should research in my previous comment.

Comment: For starters, I would suggest you work through a tutorial or two. They should give you an idea of what is possible, so that you can ask more specific questions.

Comment: thanks both for the help